# Why reset a FormGroup instead of replacing it?

Tags: angular

I could do `myForm.Reset()` but I could also do `myForm = new FormControl()`.

I understand the former will avoid subscription leaks if there are subscriptions on the form state, but are there other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `Reset` is more apparent when working with a form that contains multiple controls.

```
this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                     Validators.minLength(3),
                     Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  productCode: ['', Validators.required],
  starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
  tags: this.fb.array([]),
  description: ''
});
```

Then a form reset resets the entire form without having to recreate the entire form group.